# symfony is hallucinating connection name

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

Here is my config/databases.yml:

```
all:
  galapagos:
    class: sfDoctrineDatabase
    param:
      dsn:      mysql:host=localhost;dbname=galapagos
      username: galapagos
      password: U88rnh9#g
#  survey:
#    class: sfDoctrineDatabase
#    param:
#      dsn:      mysql:host=localhost;dbname=survey
#      username: survey
#      password: U88rnh9#s
```

As you can see, there's just one connection that's not commented out.

If I delete everything in `cache/` and `log/` and then run `symfony doctrine:build-schema` and `symfony doctrine:build --all-classes`, I get this error:

```
Unknown connection: survey
```

But I'm not mentioning `survey` anywhere!

My schema doesn't mention survey:

```
$ cat config/doctrine/schema.yml | grep survey
$
```

Interestingly, I don't get the error if I only run `build-model`. The error apparently only happens for `build-forms` and `build-filters`.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went away on its own. Stupid problem, stupid solution.

Comment: Would be great if you shared the solution :)

Comment: Would be great if I knew what it was!

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove corresponding doctrine_schema_xxxx.yml files in /tmp directory as well.

Answer (score 1):

Got "Unknown connection: web" whenever I ran `symfony doctrine:build-sql`

Following on Anthony Martin, I perused my model doctrine classes and found at line 1 of one of them :

```
Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->bindComponent('WsSessions', 'web');
```

Changing `web` into `doctrine` which was the actual name of db connection entered inside `config/databases.yml`, solved the problem !

[why on earth 'web' ever happened to be written there, don't ask me ;-)]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. To solve it I got rid of the doctrine classes for any tables I had created in the schema which were at one point using the connection. Then I ran `php symfony doctrine:clean`